# Searching words from a file in another file

Tags: python, string, search

I have got 2 files:

- **access.log.13**  : a simple access log from a web server.
- **bots.txt** : that contains spider's and crawlers names, each one in a different line, for example: googlebot mj12bot baidu etc etc

I would like to create a third file "**hits.txt**" with all the lines from "access.log.13" that contains any of the words from the file "spiders.txt"

This is my little Frankeinstein:

```
file_working = file("hits.txt", "wt")

file_1_logs = open("access.log.13", "r")
file_2_bots = open("bots.txt", "r")
file_3_hits = open("hits.txt", "a")

list_1 = arxiu_1_logs.readlines()
list_2 = arxiu_2_bots.readlines()

file_3_hits.write("Lines with bots: \n \n")

for i in list_2:
    for j in list_1:
     if i in j:          
         file_3_hits.write(j)

arxiu_1_logs.close()
arxiu_2_bots.close()
```

It doesn't work as i would like cause i only get hits when the line in bots.txt is exactly the same than any line in access.log.13. Thx

Comment: This immediately struck me as a task more appropriate for shell-scripting. So if you are interested: `grep -Fe "$(cat bots.txt|tr " " \\n| tr -d \\r| tr -s \\n)" access.log.13 > hits.txt` performs this function... . To explain that commandline, it uses tr to convert spaces -> newlines, delete carriage returns, and finally compress any runs of multiple newlines into single newlines. The result is given to grep -F as the expression (it expects one pattern per line)... TL;DR: "grep -F can do this already"

Comment: Thx a lot! i will add this grep example to my evernote. But i would like to learn the same with python. Thx again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in a more pythonish way:

```
with open('spiders.txt') as fh:
    words = set(re.split(r'[ \n\r]+', fh.read())) # set of searched words

with open('access.log.13') as file_in, \
     open('hits.txt', 'w') as file_out:
    for line in file_in:
        if any(word in line for word in words): # look for any of the words
            file_out.write(line)
```

Or you can use even nicer comprehension:

```
with open(...) as file_in, open (...) as file_out: # same as previously
    good_lines = (line for line in file_in if any(word in line for word in words))
    for good_line in good_lines:
        file_out.write(good_line)
```

Comment: Jakub M. your first option works very well and i understand the code (great). Now i'm working with the second option :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace the if with this:

```
if j.find(i) != -1
```

Comment: I replaced the line:
   if i in j:
with your suggestion:
    if j.find(i) != -1

But the terminal hits me with "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" pointing the number "1!

Comment: @Quendi a ':' was missing at the end of the line.